# What would be the most diffident way of file copying using java?

Tags: java, file, copy

I need to write a application to copy files(*.jar,*.xml,*.sql,*.exe) from different location to some specific location What would be the most efficient way of file copy using java?

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.nio.file.Files.File#copy` which intoduced in java 7. Example -

```
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered, in some detail, in [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) tutorial